# AutoMapper (v9 & 10) maps successfully when Destination property missing in Source should cause failure

Tags: c#, automapper

Is this a bug or is there an explanation?

If I understand the AutoMapper documentation correctly, I should be failing when no Source member/mapping is found for Destination member

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html?highlight=Default#selecting-members-to-validate

Testrepo https://github.com/austinmfb/AutoMapperTests

Setup

```
    public class OuterDest
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int AdditionalValue { get; set; }

        public DataClass1 DataClass { get; set; }

        public InnerDest Inner { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerDest
    {
        public int OtherValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class OuterSource
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public InnerSource Inner { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerSource
    {
        public int OtherValue { get; set; }
    }

Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> mapperConfigExpression =
    cfg =>
    {
        //MemberList.Source or Destination do not seem to change result
        cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>() 
            //.ForMember(d => d.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Value))
        ;
        
        cfg.CreateMap<InnerSource,  InnerDest>();
    };
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mapperConfigExpression);
```

Test

```
var mapped = mapper.Map<OuterDest>(source);
```

Runs successfully when according to docs, it should fail...

```
mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); 
/* returns expected failure members in exception message

Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
==========================================================================================================
OuterSource -> OuterDest (Destination member list)
AutoMapperConsole.TestClasses.Sources.OuterSource -> AutoMapperConsole.TestClasses.Destinations.OuterDest (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
AdditionalValue
DataClass

*/
```

Expected unmapped members exception since additional members exist in Destination types that are not in source per docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behaviour.

You're supposed to always validate your configuration at development time and any errors solved by the time the code is released.

`Map` doesn't validate and only fails when it must.